# Progress bar sometimes change color

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I use a ProgressBar in a layout like this:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_small_icon_size"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        />
```

It's inflated with the activity layout and basically the only thing I do with it is calling `setVisibility(...)` to either `VISIBLE` or `GONE`.

Now to my issue... Most of the times when I enter my app and the progress bar is shown, the color is set to the `accent color` (in this case orange) but every now and then when I close the app and quickly reenter, it's `gray`...

When similar things have happend in the past it's because the `ApplicationContext` has been used when creating the view, hence not providing the proper theme/style. However in this case everything is defined in the XML that's later used in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)`, so it should not be a Context issue.

Anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

app takes some time to load styles around 1-2 sec depends on device/firmware speed. to make sure you will have always the same colour - use firmware based styles, they have no need to be loaded and are ready to use.